# Uninitialized constant controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

In `routes.rb`, I used `resources nicknames`. In `nickname_controller`, I did:

```
def index
    @nick_name = current_user.nicknames.build
    @nick_names = current_user.nicknames.all
  end

def create
    @nick_name = current_user.nicknames.build(nn_create_param)
    if @nick_name.save
      flash[:success]= 'Name created'
      redirect_to nickname_path
    else
      flash[:danger]= "Name can't be created"
      redirect_to nickname_path
    end
  end
```

In index view file,

```
<%= form_for @nick_name do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :nickname %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, it says `uninitialized constant NicknamesController`.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: What is your controller class name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Controller name has to be pluralized.

```
nicknames_controller.rb

class NicknamesController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Yeah its nick_names_controller.rb . But still its not working. My model name is nickname.rb instead of nick_name.rb. Is that a problem?

Comment: Is your model called `NickName` or `Nickname`? Because if it is `Nickname` you don't need the underscore.

Comment: Then the controller file and class has to be named as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller file name should be `nicknames_controller.rb` not `nickname_controller.rb`. And your controller class name should be `NicknamesController` and not `NicknameController`.

Comment: Yeah its nick_names_controller.rb . But still its not working

Comment: There should be no underscope between "nick" and "name". Please read the rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) carefully.